# How to fix react-native token getting issue?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

I'm trying to send notifications via firebase with react-native. It's fine when sending locally, but getting this error when starting to receive tokens. My RN version: 0.69

```
....
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
import firebase from "@react-native-firebase/app";
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";
export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages().then((res)=>console.log(res)).catch((e)=>console.log(e));
    firebase.messaging().hasPermission()
      .then((enabled) => {
        firebase.messaging().getToken().then(token => console.log(token));
      })
  }

  render() {
    return <View></View>
  }
}
PushNotification.configure({
  onRegister: function (token) {
    console.log("TOKEN:", token);
  },
  onNotification: function (notification) {
    console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
  },
onNotification will be called (Android)
  onAction: function (notification) {
    console.log("ACTION:", notification.action);
    console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
  },

  onRegistrationError: function(err) {
    console.error(err.message, err);
  },
  permissions: {
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  },


  popInitialNotification: true,

  requestPermissions: true,
});
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/b85Un.png)

I updated firebase/app and firebase/messaging.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I have attached my code, I think there is a problem here; `firebase.messaging().getToken().then(token => console.log(token));`